# Jackson: How to check if it is possible to parse text to POJO without error handling?

Tags: java, json, jackson

If I want to convert a string to POJO via ObjectMapper I need to wrap up my code every time with try-catch block and ignore errors.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

try {
    mapper.readValue(body, A.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // NOP
}

try {
    mapper.readValue(body, B.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // NOP
}

throw new RuntimeException("Could not parse the response body");
```

Is it possible to check before invocation of method `readValue` if a string convertible to POJO class?

Answer (score 0):

Yes but It could return null.
Configuring object mapper to not fail for unknown properties would do it.

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
A a = mapper.readValue(body, A.class);

org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig
```